# How to group the words in description by cluster keywords using vector representation

Tags: python, bert-language-model

Currently I am developing a system to visualize scholarly research trends in a specific field using python Bert embedding.

I have samples data which consist the cluster of the keywords and a raw dataset of author publication to be group around 700 data.

I would like to group the every words in the descriptions column in the raw dataset based on sample keywords and represent it by name of the author using vector representations.

Below is the sample keywords that I have:

[image]

This is my raw dataset to be group :
[image]

Below is the output I would like to achieve :

[image]

This is the link for my dataset:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jOc8nhcwnjSYF_fMzQQ0Zeid1r7ST41T?usp=sharing

Help appreciated!